# GeoTools: How to build a point? (imports issue)

Tags: gis, geotools, osgeo

I'm following the [GeoTools documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html) and found this:

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(45, 15);
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(coord);
```

When I put it in intellij IDE, for each class there are several suggested imports to use. What import I need to select?

Alternative way (with same issue) is:

```
GeometryBuilder builder = new GeometryBuilder(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
Point point = builder.createPoint(45, 15);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt you can always read the documentation, for example [JTSFactoryFinder](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/index.html?org/geotools/geometry/jts/JTSFactoryFinder.html) returns a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory`, once you know that the other pieces fall into place as:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
```

Meanwhile your [GeometryBuilder](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/GeometryBuilder.html) is an `org.geotools.geometry.GeometryBuilder` which leads to the following imports:

```
import org.geotools.geometry.GeometryBuilder;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.opengis.geometry.primitive.Point;
```